# jQuery can't refresh page with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sorry to post with my question but I really don't understand. There are some moments like this one where I have the impression that nothing work in web.

I'm trying to do something pretty simple, I just want to reload a page and add a parameter by clicking on a button with jQuery. I searched and of course I found solutions but it doesn't work for me and I really don't understand why.

I tried several solutions but none works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnDL").click(function() {
        /*window.location.href = window.location.href.replace( /[\?#].*|$/, "?dl=1" );*/

        /*if(!window.location.hash) {
            window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?dl=1");
        }*/

        /*var url = new URL(window.location.href);
        url.searchParams.set('dl','1');
        location.reload();*/

        var url = window.location.href;
        url += '?dl=1'
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Here is my code (I let some solutions I tried in comment), this doesn't work, when I click on my button it just refresh the page but the URL is still the same.

I think you've seen this question a lot of times so sorry for the inconvenience.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming the event does fire, your code should add the parameter. There is nothing there to suggest it wouldn't. Confirm the event fires (put an alert in the callback) and check the console for any errors. You are also missing a semicolon after the concatenating line.

Comment: Yes I didn't precise but I tried with an alert for each case and there isn't any error. The window.location.href just doesn't change ..

Comment: Why don't you use HTML form to submit parameter on button click? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: I didn't think about it because the treatment is on the same page but yes it works. And also, I wanted to succeed to refresh a this page with jquery, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnDL").click(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "?dl=1";
});
});
```

try this

Comment: Works fine in Chrome 67.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it on Google Chrome and it is appending id with the url. Try it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnDL").click(function() {

        var url = window.location.href;
        alert(url);
        url += '?dl=1'
        window.location.href = url;
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id='btnDL'>
 Click Me
</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work either.. I'll use a form, thank you for your help but the problem is probably from the entire site, I don't know.